# Char to NSString ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, char

```
NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile"];
NSData *bytes = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSUInteger len = [bytes length];    
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [bytes bytes], len);
NSMutableString *fileContents = [NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    char curChar = byteData[i];
    [fileContents appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", curChar]];
}
```

Putting a breakpoint right after `char curChar = byteData[i]`, I see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IeiQ.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9CAK.png 
How do I append to `fileContents` exactly what is shown in the image (\x02, \xd0 etc)? Currently all I get are weird characters like Ð
I've seen a lot of questions about how to convert a char to NSString but nothing does what I want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different format:

```
[fileContents appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\x%02x", (unsigned)curChar]];
```

EDIT: To save typing you can use `appendFormat:` (as pointed out in the now deleted answer from Nikolai Ruhe).

Answer (score 0):

*If you mean you want literally backslash-x-0-2, then see @trojanfoe's answer. If you mean you want "the character with value 2," then read on.*

What encoding is the file in? You can't talk about a string without considering its encoding. If it's "just a string of bytes" then that isn't an `NSString`; it's an `NSData` and should be treated that way.

Once you know the encoding, then you shouldn't need the `NSData` step. Just use `[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:]`.